# Why does "return" function strangely in recursive functions?

Tags: java, recursion, return

```
public class Search {

    public int Search(int[] sortedArray, int halfwayPoint, int searchNumber ) {

        if(sortedArray[halfwayPoint] == searchNumber){
            return halfwayPoint;
        }

        else if((halfwayPoint < sortedArray.length -1 ) && sortedArray[halfwayPoint] < searchNumber){
            return Search(sortedArray, halfwayPoint + 1, searchNumber );
        }

        else if(halfwayPoint > 0 && sortedArray[halfwayPoint] > searchNumber){
            return Search(sortedArray, halfwayPoint - 1, searchNumber );
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Just a curious question on why the two basic binary search methods return different values if the return is ommitted when compared to just calling the method instead of returning the method in the elseifs

```
public class Search {

    public int Search(int[] sortedArray, int halfwayPoint, int searchNumber ) {

        if(sortedArray[halfwayPoint] == searchNumber){
            return halfwayPoint;
        }

        else if((halfwayPoint < sortedArray.length -1 ) && sortedArray[halfwayPoint] < searchNumber){
            Search(sortedArray, halfwayPoint + 1, searchNumber );
        }

        else if(halfwayPoint > 0 && sortedArray[halfwayPoint] > searchNumber){
            Search(sortedArray, halfwayPoint - 1, searchNumber );
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: "when compared to just calling the method" if you just call the method and ignore the result, and don't stop execution at that point.... it's going to give a different result.

Comment: If you say `Search(...)` without `return`, it just calls the method, ignores the value the callee returned, and continues execution. In your case, `if` is exited and `return -1;` is called which terminates `Search()` call with `-1` as the result.

Comment: But shouldn't the recursive function repeat until the halfwayPoint is returned regardless? Or is the order of operations mean the if == search number comparison is only done once without returning from the Search?

Comment: @ryg00007 no: a value is only returned when you ask for it to be returned. If you invoke a method and ignore the result, the result is ignored.

Comment: Yes but if the number is in the binary search then it should hit the "return halfwaypoint" line at some point in the recursive call and thus return something, which it seemingly discards. I'm asking why the need for the nested return in Java,

Comment: Yeputons seems to have it right, that seems like a rather odd design choice, is there any reason as to why Java does that or where it would be useful?

Comment: @ryg00007 I'm actually struggling to understand your question. Your comment "shouldn't the recursive function repeat until the halfwayPoint is returned" seems to imply that the returned value should somehow cascade up through the recursive calls without the need for an explicit return statement in the calling method. I can't really see how that would work. As far as I know every programming language makes the exact same "rather odd design choice". Though many functional languages designate the return value implicitly rather than explicitly.